# Passing parameters from one jsp file to an included jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet controller for a jsp file. I pass some parameters to this file when loading it, via `request.setAttribute()`, from the servlet. However, I need to include another nested jsp from the main jsp file. Will the nested file have access to the params which were sent? If not, how can I pass those params to the nested file?

Comment: Surprised you didn't try it and see what happened. You've got nearly 30k rep on here! :-)

Comment: @ouflak Having 30k rep doesn't mean I shouldn't optimize my time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the nested jsp will see request scoped attributes set from servlet controller.

Answer (score 3):

use jstl's set method in the parent jsp and use the same variable in jspf.

In parent jsp.

```
<c:set var="foo" value="bar"/>
```

In included jspf.

```
<h2>The included parameter is ${foo}</h2>
```

Also you can access all the attributes set inside a servlet using `request.setAttribute()` in the jsp page using EL e.g `${attributeName}`